# WPF borderless window resize with inner-margins

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window which looks like this in the designer:

[image: wpf designer screenshot]

There is an area of space between the inner-grid and the edges of the window because between those two elements, a DropShadow is drawn.

My issue with this is that I can't use WPF's native tools for re-sizing the window.  If I set ResizeMode to CanResize, the handles are transparent and thus you can't actually grab onto them.  If I set ResizeMode to CanResizeWithGrip, I can see the grip, but it's in the lower right of the entire window.  Is there any way I could have the resizing handles show where the inner-grid starts instead of on the outer edges of the form?

Here is the designer with the grip:

[image: designer with grip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating custom Window style. Here is implementation example:

DropShadowedWindowStyle.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="DropShadowedWindow.DropShadowedWindowStyle">
    <Style x:Key="DropShadowedWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResize"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border Margin="10">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Name="ContentPresenter" ClipToBounds="True"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                            <Grid x:Name="ResizeDummies">
                                <Line Cursor="SizeNS" MouseDown="p_OnSizeN" X1="0" X2="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" StrokeThickness="4" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Line>
                                <Line Cursor="SizeNS" MouseDown="p_OnSizeS" X1="0" X2="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" StrokeThickness="4" Y1="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Y2="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Line>
                                <Line Cursor="SizeWE" MouseDown="p_OnSizeW" X1="0" X2="0" StrokeThickness="4" Y1="0" Y2="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Stroke="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Line>
                                <Line Cursor="SizeWE" MouseDown="p_OnSizeE" X1="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" X2="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" StrokeThickness="4" Y1="0" Y2="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Stroke="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Line>
                                <Rectangle Cursor="SizeNWSE" MouseDown="p_OnSizeNW" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <Rectangle Cursor="SizeNESW" MouseDown="p_OnSizeNE" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                <Rectangle Cursor="SizeNESW" MouseDown="p_OnSizeSW" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <Rectangle Cursor="SizeNWSE" MouseDown="p_OnSizeSE" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize">
                            <Setter TargetName="ResizeDummies" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize">
                            <Setter TargetName="ResizeDummies" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

DropShadowedWindowStyle.xaml.cs:

```
namespace DropShadowedWindow
{
    public partial class DropShadowedWindowStyle
    {
        #region Helper Functions

            /// <summary>
            /// Return WinApi window handler from WPF window
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="w"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            protected static IntPtr p_GetHW(Window w)
            {
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
                return helper.Handle;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get templated parent window, if it exists
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            protected Window p_GetTemplatedWindow(object sender)
            {
                var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
                if (element != null)
                {
                    var w = element.TemplatedParent as Window;
                    if (w != null) return w;
                }
                return null;
            }


        #endregion Helper Functions

        #region Window Event Hanlders

            protected enum SizingAction
            {
                North = 3,
                South = 6,
                East = 2,
                West = 1,
                NorthEast = 5,
                NorthWest = 4,
                SouthEast = 8,
                SouthWest = 7
            }

            protected void p_OnSizeS(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.South); }
            protected void p_OnSizeN(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.North); }
            protected void p_OnSizeE(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.East); }
            protected void p_OnSizeW(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.West); }
            protected void p_OnSizeNW(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.NorthWest); }
            protected void p_OnSizeNE(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.NorthEast); }
            protected void p_OnSizeSE(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.SouthEast); }
            protected void p_OnSizeSW(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { p_OnSize(sender, SizingAction.SouthWest); }


            /// <summary>
            /// Switch to resize mode by dragging corners
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="action"></param>
            protected void p_OnSize(object sender, SizingAction action)
            {
                if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    var w = p_GetTemplatedWindow(sender);
                    if (w != null && w.WindowState == WindowState.Normal) p_DragSize(p_GetHW(w), action);
                }
            }


        #endregion Window Event Hanlders

        #region P/Invoke

            const int WmSyscommand = 0x112;
            const int ScSize = 0xF000;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
            private static extern IntPtr p_SendMessage(IntPtr h_wnd, uint msg, IntPtr w_param, IntPtr l_param);

            /// <summary>
            /// Activate resize mode
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="handle"></param>
            /// <param name="sizing_action"></param>
            private void p_DragSize(IntPtr handle, SizingAction sizing_action)
            {
                p_SendMessage(handle, WmSyscommand, (IntPtr)(ScSize + sizing_action), IntPtr.Zero);
                p_SendMessage(handle, 514, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Note: this example doesn't contain elements to move, close, maximize and minimize window. You can see how do them in this project https://github.com/D-Key/whosh or this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

You can also see another approach here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02fb62be-4550-4036-8a72-fe53e43a6414/showing-resizegrip-on-a-window-with-a-shadow